# Pagination while sorting a non unique text column

Tags: postgresql, order-by, pagination

What are the ways to *paginate* a table on a non unique text column?

On a unique `timestamp` column, one can create an index on it and execute the following to move forward

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE created > '<last element created timestamp>' ORDER BY created ASC LIMIT 20;
```

If it is a numerical primary key

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id > 100 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 20;
```

But what can one do when the table is ordered by non unique text column (`first_name` for example)?

First thing that comes to mind is the `OFFSET` method, but there are performance penalties on large tables.

Alternatively, one could use a cursor, but the internet agrees that it not recommended way on a *public* web application.

Comment: Note the important thing here is not that it is a text column, but rather that is non unique.  Your first example with the timestamps might actually be wrong, if there are ties between timestamps (which there easily could be, depending on the table is populated)

Comment: Indeed. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution that performs well would be being smart with indexes.

First, create an index on two columns, one being your non unique text column and a second one being your id column (it can be any column that can be differentiated between non unique text column rows):

```sql
CREATE INDEX user_name_uuid_idx
    ON public.user USING btree
    (name COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, uuid ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

NOTE: the order of columns does matter. Use the same order that is used in the `select` query

Then use this query to get *x* page.

```sql
SELECT * FROM user WHERE (name, uuid) > ('Misty Wyman', '070d905d-2155-492f-b811-2c9d30015299') ORDER BY name, uuid LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Cool, I did not know the `(x, y) > (a, b)` notation! Is it POSTGRES dialect, or is it SQL standard?

Comment: How to take advantage of the index also while getting the previous page with ORDER BY name DESC, uuid DESC?